# Julia: Understanding Multiple dispatch for OOP

Tags: oop, julia, multiple-dispatch

Lets say I have the following types:

```
type cat
  cry:: String
  legs:: Int
  fur:: String
end


type car
  noise::String
  wheels::Int
  speed::Int
end


Lion = cat("meow", 4, "fuzzy")
vw = car("honk", 4, 45)
```

And I want to add a method `describe` to both of them which prints the data inside them. Is it best to use methods to do it this way:

```
describe(a::cat) = println("Type: Cat"), println("Cry:", a.cry, " Legs:",a.legs,  " fur:", a.fur);
describe(a::car) = println("Type: Car"), println("Noise:", a.noise, " Wheels:", a.wheels, " Speed:", a.speed)

describe(Lion)
describe(vw)
```

Output:

```
Type: Cat
Cry:meow Legs:4 fur:fuzzy
Type: Car
Noise:honk Wheels:4 Speed:45
```

Or should I use a function like in this question I posted before: [Julia: What is the best way to set up a OOP model for a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814150/julia-what-is-the-best-way-to-set-up-a-oop-model-for-a-library)

Which method is more efficient?

Most `Methods` examples in the [documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/methods/) are simple functions, if I wanted a more complex `Method` with loops or if statements are they possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I recommend using a capital letter as the first letter of a type name - this is an extremely consistent thing in Julia style, so not doing it would definitely be awkward for people using your code.

As you are doing multi-statement methods, you should probably write them as full functions, e.g.

```
function describe(a::cat)
  println("Type: Cat")
  println("Cry:", a.cry, " Legs:", a.legs,  " fur:", a.fur)
end
function describe(a::car)
  println("Type: Car")
  println("Noise:", a.noise, " Wheels:", a.wheels, " Speed:", a.speed)
end
```

Typically the one-liner version is used only for simple single statements.

May also be worth noting that we are making one *function*, with two *methods*, in case that wasn't clear from the manual.

Finally, you could also add a *method* to the base Julia *print* function, e.g.

```
function Base.print(io::IO, a::cat)
  println(io, "Type: Cat")
  print(io, "Cry:", a.cry, " Legs:", a.legs,  " fur:", a.fur)
end
function Base.print(io::IO, a::car)
  println(io, "Type: Car")
  print(io, "Noise:", a.noise, " Wheels:", a.wheels, " Speed:", a.speed)
end
```

(if you call `println`, it'll call `print` internally and add the `\n` automatically)